# Dataframe find rows out of sequence based on condition in column

Tags: python, dataframe

I got a a column of type object (`df.columntype`).
I have selected rows with types `'A'` and `'B'` of interest:

```
subset = df[df.columntype.isin(['A', 'B'])]
```

For each `'A'`, there should be a `'B'` after, so the sequence should include the same number of As and Bs in the order A-B-A-B etc. However, the count of `df[df.columntype == 'B']` is higher than `df[df.columntype == 'A']`. What I want to do is to spot the rows where B comes without its parent A. How can I do this?

Here is a sample of the data subset (see above)

```
    timeframe  columntype   
2   2021-05-13  A
3   2021-05-13  B   
26  2021-05-14  A
27  2021-05-14  B
85  2021-05-15  A
```

Comment: Is `type` the name of the column? Also, can you give examples?

Comment: please add a sample of your data.

Comment: Is it possible to share first 10 rows of the dataframe to see how the data looks.

Comment: Please see updated question @JoshFriedlander yes but I changed it just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways off the top of my head to achieve this:

Sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['B','A','B','A','B','C','B','D','B']})
df

  type
0    B
1    A
2    B
3    A
4    B
5    C
6    B
7    D
8    B
```

First method:

```
set_B = set(np.where(df.type == 'B')[0])
set_A = set(np.where(df.type.shift(1) == 'A')[0])

orphans = sorted(set(set_B).difference(set_A))

# or:
# orphans = list(set(set_B).difference(set_A))
# orphans.sort()

df.iloc[orphans,:]

  type
0    B
8    B
6    B
```

Second method:

```
subset = df[df.type.isin(['A', 'B'])]

arr_bool = np.ediff1d(subset.index) != 1
arr_bool = np.insert(arr_bool,0,df.type[0]=='B')

non_consec = subset[arr_bool]
orphans = non_consec[non_consec.type == 'B']
orphans

  type
0    B
6    B
8    B
```

Comment: Yup, except I think OP wanted the complement of this, ie the non-orphans (question is a bit confusing)

Comment: @JoshFriedlander: "What I want to do is to spot the rows where B comes without its parent A". I take this to mean: I want any row with a "B", where the previous row does not contain "A". No?

Comment: ok, I guess you're right

Comment: I just tried your first method. It is returning all B rows that dont have A before, which is great. But indexes are not in order, they seem to be randomly place. Is there a condition to sort the search of iloc? thanks

Comment: Yes @JoshFriedlander that is right

Comment: Right, after `orphans = list(set(set_B).difference(set_A))` add `orphans.sort()`. Updated this in the answer as well.

Comment: not sure why it makes it random without the sorting, but it works now. Thanks for the help. @ouroboros1

Comment: It's because `sets` in Python do not preserve the order of inserted elements. Actually, while my `sort()` solution just now should work, it's verbose. We could just use `orphans = sorted(set(set_B).difference(set_A))`